# JQuery JFlow - slideshow - cannot move 'left' 'right' buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use JQuery to show N pictures in slide. So I put everything as needed, have to define two left/right links so user can scroll pictures. Problem is that JQuery engine automatically put those two on lower left and right corner of web page.

Is there a way to tell JQuery not to do that, so I can position them where needed?

How it looks now you can see at:

http://ante.komponenta.com/index.php?module=Pagesetter&func=viewpub&tid=3&pid=11&_tpl=overview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think this is best example of jflow slideshow :)
http://www.raghibsuleman.com/jquery-jflow-slideshow